# How to Save Excel file to SharePoint using Office Excel-add-ins

Tags: excel-addins

I want to store excel file from office-add-ins to SharePoint Online, I am able to store file using rest API but I didn't got data inside the file, i tried this solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word